# How to use a loop but not change the object (cursor)?

Tags: php, object, foreach, cursor

I just figured out that my print handler does change the cursor of objects. (That means viewing an object does change it and I would prefer not to do so.)

For example if I print a result of an mysqli_query, I would need to add something like $result->data_seek(0); before I can go ahead.

I tried to use clone instead of the object but apparently one cannot clone mysqli_queries.

Is there a way how I can handle a abitrary object without changing it?

I simplified my method to keep the focus on the foreach loop.

Thank you for your help in advance!
Peter

```
private static function _recursivePrintHandler($input, string $tab)
{

  if(is_array($input))
  {
    $echoStr = 'array'. PHP_EOL;
  }
  elseif(is_object($input))
  {
    $echoStr = 'object'. PHP_EOL;
    //$input = clone $input; // does not work, i.e. one cannot clone mysqli objects :-(
  }
  else 
  {
    return 'UNKNOWN TYPE';
  }

  $echoStr .= $tab. '('. PHP_EOL;
  $tabAdditional = '    ';

  foreach ($input as $key => $value) 
  {
    $echoStr .= $tab. '['. $key. '] => '. CallSomeThing(). PHP_EOL;
  }
  $echoStr .= $tab. ')';
  return $echoStr;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered a simpler solution. Get all the results into an array. You can then wander up and down the array as often as you like

Comment: I use the getArrayFromSqlResult() method that you mentioned.
I wrote the MyPrint() method for purposes like 
"oh my code does not work. Let's display inputs and see if there is maybe something wrong with the input."
Especially for such a purpose it is very important that I do not change the input just to view it. It is meant to be a work around of the problem that print_r() does not look very nice when viewed in HTML